# Understanding the logic flow of mock tests

Tags: unit-testing, symfony, mocking, phpunit

In an effort to learn the logic flow of mock tests I've unsuccessfully reproduced a test from a [Symfony article](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/testing/database.html) using code from my application.

Background: Volunteer entity extends the abstract class Person, which extends the FOSUserBundle model User.  Person includes methods for `firstName`, `lastName`, and `name`.  Name returns `lastName, firstName`. The test that appears below returns this:

```
--- Expected
+++ Actual
@@ @@
-'Borko, Benny'
+', '
```

How should this test be modified?  Better yet, how do you tell when it's your test design and not the system under test that's failing?

#### Edit: see result of applying proposed solution below

#### Edit #2:

Not sure if this is relevant: Volunteer and two other entities are mapped via Inheritance Mapping to the Person entity (see PUGXMultiUserBundle).

The test:

```
use Truckee\MatchingBundle\Entity\Volunteer;

class MockVolunteerTest extends \PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    public function testFullName()
    {
        // First, mock the object to be used in the test
        $volunteer = $this->getMock('\Truckee\MatchingBundle\Entity\Volunteer');
        $volunteer->expects($this->once())
                ->method('getFirstName')
                ->will($this->returnValue('Benny'));
        $volunteer->expects($this->once())
                ->method('getLastName')
                ->will($this->returnValue('Borko'));

        // Now, mock the repository so it returns the mock of the volunteer
        $volunteerRepository = $this->getMockBuilder('\Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository')
                ->disableOriginalConstructor()
                ->getMock();
        $volunteerRepository->expects($this->once())
                ->method('find')
                ->will($this->returnValue($volunteer));

        // Last, mock the EntityManager to return the mock of the repository
        $em = $this->getMockBuilder('\Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager')
                ->disableOriginalConstructor()
                ->getMock();
        $em->expects($this->once())
                ->method('getRepository')
                ->will($this->returnValue($volunteerRepository));

        $user = new Volunteer();
        $this->assertEquals('Borko, Benny', $user->getName());
    }
}
```

#### Proposed solution:

```
class VolunteerTest extends \PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    /**
     * @var Volunteer
     */
    protected $object;

    /**
     * Sets up the fixture, for example, opens a network connection.
     * This method is called before a test is executed.
     */
    protected function setUp()
    {
        $this->object = new Volunteer();
    }

    public function testGetterAndSetter() {
        $this->assertNull($this->object->setFirstName("Benny"));
        $this->assertEquals("Benny", $this->object->getFirstName());

        $this->assertNull($this->object->setLastName("Borko"));
        $this->assertEquals("Borko", $this->object->getLastName());

        $this->assertEquals('Borko, Benny', $this->object->getName());
    }    
}
```

#### Test results:

> Failed asserting that Truckee\MatchingBundle\Entity\Volunteer Object
>   &0000000067c9c33f00000000680c6030 (
>       'id' => null ...
>       'credentialsExpireAt' => null ) is null.

Comment: Take a look at Symfony's example code.  The reason why all of that repository mocking works is because they are calling a function that actually calls the `find()` method from their repository.  They have `calculateTotalSalary($id)` which calls `$employee = $employeeRepository->find($id);`.  You aren't calling any sort of `find()` method anyway, you're just testing the entity.

Comment: @JasonRoman I'd pretty well figured that out.  But if I replace `$user = new Volunteer();` with `$user = $entityManager->find(1);` I get `Missing argument 2 for Mock_ObjectManager...`.  If instead `$user = $personRepository->find(1);` I get `Failed asserting that null matches...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer here is that the test is an inappropriate use of mock testing.  After reading the article ["An Introduction to Mock Object Testing"](http://www.sitepoint.com/an-introduction-to-mock-object-testing/) it became clear that the technique is to **mock the dependencies** of the system (object) under test, not the object itself. In the test I attempted, the Volunteer entity was the SUT so it should not have been mocked.

Answer (score 1):

The main goal of mocks is to test repositories or services. There is a easier way to test your entity:

```
class VolunteerTest extends \PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {

    /**
     * @var Volunteer
     */
    protected $object;

    /**
     * Sets up the fixture, for example, opens a network connection.
     * This method is called before a test is executed.
     */
    protected function setUp()
    {
        $this->object = new Volunteer();
    }

    public function testGetterAndSetter() {
        $this->assertNull($this->object->setFirstName("Benny"));
        $this->assertEquals("Benny", $this->object->getFirstName());

        $this->assertNull($this->object->setLastName("Borko"));
        $this->assertEquals("Borko", $this->object->getLastName());
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks.  How might one test the `getName()` function?

Comment: Just add another assertion:  `$this->assertEquals('Borko, Benny', $user->getName());`